# C++ calculate line of best fit using chi squared arrhenius

Tags: c++, math, chemistry

so i'm looking at this web page at the moment - its a chemistry /maths question that gives you data for rate vs temp to calculate the activation energy of the substance - the data is on the page & in the code

http://faculty.weber.edu/ewalker/Chem2990/Chem3020/WebPages/1_11.htm

in it gives values for T and k(rate)

as it says you can plot 1/T vs ln(k) to calc Ea (activation energy) & A(pre-exp factor)

but rather than do that make a programme that iterates chi^2 calculations to evaluate the lowest one - which will be associated with an activation energy

Arrhenious is : // k = A * exp(-Ea/(RT))

chi^2 = ((observed - expected)^2)/expected

where observed is the values of k given on the web page and expected is the estimate made when using an estimate Ea - which starts at 100

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>



using namespace std;
int main()
{

long double chi1;
long double chi2;
long double T[8] = { 400,430,460,490,510,540,610,7000, };
long double k[8] = { 0.011,0.035,0.105,0.343,0.789,2.17,20.0,145, };

long double kJ;
long double R = 8.31446;
long double ki[8];
long double OE[8];    
long double dEa = 10000;
int i = 0;
int dp = 5;

// k = A * exp(-Ea/(RT)) 

long double Ea = 100000;
long double A = 1.100e+12;

 // I’m keeping A constant at 1.1*10^12
 // Then calculating Chi Squared from a starting Ea value of 100000




// k = A * exp(-Ea/(RT))
do {

    do { 
        chi1 = 0; chi2 = 0; 
        i = 0; 
        while (i < 8)             {
            ki[i] = A*exp(-E / (R*T[i])); 
            OE[i] = pow(k[i] - ki[i], 2); 
            chi1 = chi1 + (OE[i]); 
            i++;
        }
        i = 0; 
        while (i < 8)
        {
            ki[i] = A*exp(-(E + dE) / (R*T[i]));
            OE[i] = pow(k[i] - ki[i], 2); 
            chi2 = chi2 + (OE[i]);
            i++;
        }



        if (chi1 > chi2) { 
            E = E + dE; 

        }

    } while (chi2 < chi1);

    do { 
        chi1 = 0; chi2 = 0; 
        i = 0; 
        while (i < 8) 
        {
            ki[i] = A*exp(-E / (R*T[i])); 
            OE[i] = pow(k[i] - ki[i], 2); 
            chi1 = chi1 + (OE[i]);
            i++;
        }


        i = 0;             
        while (i < 8)
        {
            ki[i] = A*exp(-(E - dE) / (R*T[i]));
            OE[i] = pow(k[i] - ki[i], 2); 
            chi2 = chi2 + (OE[i]);
            i++;
        }



        if (chi1 > chi2) { 
            E = E - dE; 

        }



    } while (chi2 < chi1);

    dE = dE / 10;

} while (dE > pow(10, 2 - dp));







kJ = E / 1000;
cout << dE << endl;
cout << “Ea = " << fixed << setprecision(dp) << kJ << "kJ" << endl;
cout << “Chi squared = " << chi1 << endl;


return 0;


}
```

basically my value for chi^2 and for Ea don't match my excel results

- any ideas?

Comment: `basically my value for chi^2 and for Ea don't match my excel results`  Please tell us what the differences are in these results.  First off, don't expect floating point to calculate the exact value you expect.  Binary floating point does not work exactly the same as what you see in your math or chemistry book, as there is rounding errors to consider.

Comment: The highest temp in your source is 7000, rather than 700 - is this your error ?